# Adamantium and healing in The Wolverine

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, the-wolverine

In the last parts of The Wolverine:

Yashida, via the Silver Samurai, drilled into Wolverine's cut-off claws and presumably sucked all the adamantium out of him, as evidenced by his claws becoming pure bone after. However, Yashida becomes visually younger as the adamantium was being removed from Wolverine. Was Wolverine's healing ability getting transferred as well?

Or did the movie become confused with regards to the relation between Wolverine's adamantium and his healing ability?

Comment: Nothing is suppose to be able to cut through adamantiium.

Comment: @John, the OP's description is accurate.  However rikitikitik I'm very confused particularly with Magneto's appearance - this implies he didn't take all the adamantium out!

Comment: But the confusing part is that adamantium can not be cut, it is the hardest and densest metal there is :D

Comment: @bobbi Except for Vibranium.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Silver Samurai drilled into the stumps of Wolverine's claws in order to begin the process of stealing his healing factor, but he had no interest in the adamantium. He made no       effort to collect the claws he had lopped off, or to reclaim the adamantium shavings left behind by his drilling. The adamantium in the rest of Wolverine's skeleton was unaffected.

Once the metal claws were removed, Wolverine's healing factor caused him to regrow his bony claws, similar to the ones he had had for decades before he had been infused with adamantium in the first place. He used these regrown claws in the final moments of the fight with the Silver Samurai.

Comment: Which would also explain the Magneto scene... thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The adamantium wasn't being drilled, the claws were cut in order to gain access to the bone underneath. It's more likely Yashida was tapping into wolverines bone marrow to extract the healing factor. In humans new blood cells are created within the bone marrow, so it would be realistic to presume that the bone marrow is a great place to harvest newly created and maybe the purest of wolverines cells.

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing the part as to what *yashida* exactly wanted. Yashida wanted Wolverine's healing factor to stop himself from dying. As they fight, Yashida in the guise of the *Silver Samurai* cuts off Logan's claws, and begins stealing his healing factor. From the onset of the movie, Yashida is after Logan's *healing factor* and not his admantium. When fighting and falling into the well, Yashida starts stealing Logan's healing ability, which results in the mentioned scene.

Comment: I do know that Yashida was after Wolverine's healing ability, that was never in question. Somehow, I have this notion that the drill was supposed to steal his adamantium, with the (utterly horrifying) boney claws as a result.

Answer (score 1):

It was definitely just to get to the bone marrow. All of his bones are covered in adamantium so the bone marrow wouldn't be accessible without removing it or cutting it in two. He already had plenty of the metal which he needed to build the suit.